# I need a Regular Expression to find whitespaces and replace with a dash?

Tags: regex

I thought this might work:  ^['\s+', '-', "This should be connected"\w\s]{1,}$

But something is wrong with it. Does anyone no of a regex that will place dashes between words while at the same time not placing dashes in front of the very first word or behind the very last word? And, sometimes I will only have one word so no dashes are required.

The tool I am using is www.import.io which allows me turn any website into a table of data or an API in seconds – no coding required. It uses regex and xapath to help refine and reformat the data it captures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about only RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about www.import.io, but in plain JavaScript

```
" This is my  test string   ".replace(/(\w+)\s+(?=\w)/g, "$1-")
```

has the result:

```
" This-is-my-test-string   "
```

The regex replaces every whitespace characters with dashes between words, but not at the beginning or the end of the string.

(To be more precise it replaces every group of word characters and whitespaces which are followed by a word character with the same word characters without the whitespaces and with a dash instead.)